# Inserir valores de upload num array com outro nome?

Tags: php

O meu problema é o seguinte, eu tenho um formulário onde o utilizador faz uploads, com isso tudo bem, mas eu gostaria que ele inserisse com outro nome mas se assim o for, ele insere em branco na base de dados.

```
$files=$rand."_".$_FILES['upload']['name'];
$array=implode(",", $files);
echo "<script>alert('Array: ".$array."')</script>";
```

Com o código acima, ele manda o campo `$array` vazia mas se eu fizer `$files=$_FILES['upload']['name'];` ele manda direito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caro amigo, se é que entendi sua intenção lhe recomendo utilizar diretamente os índices prefinidos da variável `$_FILES` do PHP.

Não está retornando valores por que você está usando o `implode` delimitando por "," mas o `$_FILES` lhe retorna um array de posições da seguinte forma:

```
[file] => Array
    (
        [name] => MyFile.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/php/php6hst32
        [error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
        [size] => 13
    );
```

Por isso não retorna valor de acordo com seu código, por que você não informou um índice do array para se trabalhar e não tem "," para delimitar.